# Nodejs mongodb cannot use variable content as name for array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to use a variable name for an array inside my document. Here is what i have tried

```
router.post('/location', async(req, res) => {
if(req.headers.token == process.env.API_TOKEN){
    const userid = req.body.userid
    const time = req.body.time;
    const restaurantId = req.body.restId;
    const date = new Date();
    let path = `${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth()}.${date.getFullYear()}`
    console.log(path);
    collection.update(
        { _id: ObjectId('locations') },
        { $push: { path:  { userid,
                                date: new Date(),
                                time,
                            restId: restaurantId } } }

     )
     res.end("Analytics Data Saved");
     res.status(200);
}else{
    res.end("Unauthorized")
    res.status(400)
}
```

})

If i use it like this the result is that the array is called path. A $ sign at the beginning is throwing the following error:

> MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$path' in '$path' is not valid for storage.

Comment: Hi there! Can you try logging the value of the object you are trying to push into `path` and share the value.

Comment: without $ it creates an array with name path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using []:

```
  let path = `${date.getDate()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getFullYear()}`
    console.log(path);
    collection.update(
        { _id: 'locations' },
        { $push: { [String(path)]:  { userid,
                                date: new Date(),
                                time,
                            restId: restaurantId } } }

     )
     res.end("Analytics Data Saved");
     res.status(200);
```